# System.Text.Json.JsonException: "The JSON value could not be converted to ConsoleApp3.Data. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."

Tags: c#

я вставил ссылку на апи-https://api.vimeworld.ru/user/name/" + nickname, а программа ругается, что нельзя преобразовать string в System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, если скобочки после  оставить пустым то будет "Необработанное пользователем исключение": System.Text.Json.JsonException: "The JSON value could not be converted to ConsoleApp3.Data. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."

Класс Data

```
public class Data
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public int level { get; set; }
        public float levelPercentage { get; set; }
        public string rank { get; set; }
        public int playedSeconds { get; set; }
        public int lastSeen { get; set; }
        public Guild guild { get; set; }
    }
```

Код

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient() { DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20 };

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            string nickname = Console.ReadLine();
            string requesUri = "https://api.vimeworld.ru/user/name/" + nickname;
            
            using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requesUri);
            using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            Data result = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Data>();
            int id = result.id;

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Текст Json - https://api.vimeworld.ru/user/name/xtrafrancyz

> [{"id":134568,"username":"xtrafrancyz","level":42,"levelPercentage":0.65967,"rank":"ADMIN","playedSeconds":10202443,"lastSeen":1636577962,"guild":{"id":401,"name":"\u041a\u0435\u043a
> \u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430 -
> \u0445\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0448\u043e","tag":null,"color":"&f","level":1,"levelPercentage":0.39652,"avatar_url":"https://mc.vimeworld.ru/launcher/guilds/401.png?t=1598021991"}}]

Comment: А где вы там увидели `Data`? Вот давайте по порядку, первый символ `[` - что это? Правильно, массив, почему тогда `.ReadFromJsonAsync<Data>();`? Внимательно следуйте тому, что у вас в JSON и все будет хорошо, ну а если нужна визуализация, то можете воспользоваться онлайн просмотром (к примеру [этот](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)), или установить плагин для браузера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON содержит массив `[]`, а не объект `{}`.

Частный случай решения для одноэлементного массива будет выглядеть так.

```cs
Data result = (await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Data[]>())[0];
```